# Problems with validation of rules in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rules

I'm having problems validating Laravel rules. I have this CRUD that receives as a parameter a Request type. I also built a StoreMultipleForm because I have two forms that need to be valid at the same time. This works fine for the SAVE, however, to INSERT it is giving errors conflicting with my CRUD Request:

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Admin\MedicosController::inserir() must be an instance of App\Http\Requests\StoreMultipleForm, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in /var/www/html/mateus/laravel/laravel-angular/app/Http/Controllers/CrudController.php on line 23
```

Here is my code

```
CrudController.php

public function action(Request $request, $action = null, $id = null)
{
        if($action === null){
                return $this->index($id);
        }

    if (!in_array($action, $this->allowedMethods)) {
        return abort(404);
    }
    return $this->$action($request, $id);
}


UserController.php

//TYPE STOREFORMREQUEST ERROR! 
public function insert(StoreFormRequest $request){
        $user = new User;
        $user->med_crm = $request->med_crm;
        $user->med_juridico = $request->med_juridico;
        $user->med_name = $request->med_name;
        $user->save();
}

public function save(StoreFormRequest $request){
        $user = new User;
        $user->med_crm = $request->med_crm;
        $user->med_juridico = $request->med_juridico;
        $user->med_name = $request->med_name;
        $user->save();
}
```

the code is not even of course, but what matters is the parameters and why SAVE works and INSERT does not.

Here is my StoreMultipleForm

```
class StoreMultipleForm extends FormRequest
{

public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    $formRequests = [
      MedicoFormRequest::class,
      ConsultorioFormRequest::class,
      //PacienteFormRequest::class
    ];

    $rules = [];

    foreach ($formRequests as $source) {
      $rules = array_merge(
        $rules,
        (new $source)->rules()
      );
    }

    return $rules;
}

public function messages()
{
    $formRequests = [
      MedicoFormRequest::class,
      ConsultorioFormRequest::class,
      //PacienteFormRequest::class
    ];

    $messages = [];

    foreach ($formRequests as $source) {
      $messages = array_merge(
        $messages,
        (new $source)->messages()
      );
    }

    return $messages;
}
```

}

my routes

```
$this->group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'namespace' => 'Admin'], 
   function(){
    $this->get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.home');
    $this->post('/admin/medicos/salvar/{id?}', 'MedicosController@salvar')->name('medicos');    
    $this->any('/admin/medicos/{action?}/{id?}', 'MedicosController@action')->name('medicos');
    $this->get('/admin/util/cidades/{uf_id}', 'UtilController@getCidadesByUf')->name('cidades');
    $this->get('/admin/especialidades/areasatuacoes/{esp_id}', 'EspecialidadeController@getAreasDeAtuacaoByEspecialidade')->name('areasatuacoes');
    $this->any('/admin/pacientes/{action?}/{id?}', 'PacientesController@action')->name('pacientes');
    $this->any('/admin/anuidades/{action?}/{id?}', 'AnuidadesController@action')->name('anuidades');    
  });
```

save and insert are not the same in true code, here is just example. MedicoFormRequest is other Request, StoreFormRequest is junction between MedicoFormRequest and ConsultorioFormRequest. My problem is than for SAVE method works, however, for INSERT is not working.

Comment: what is inserir() ?

Comment: insert** i'm brazilian

Comment: aw ok cool, just checking it wasn't a spelling mistake

Comment: What is the purpose of using `insert()` as well as `save()` here?

Comment: @MateusGonçalves Could you post your `StoreMultipleForm` code?

Comment: my guess is that you just need to include 'use App\Http\Requests\StoreMultipleForm' within your controllers, but we'll wait on more code

Comment: can you show your `StoreFormRequest` ?

Comment: Alberto Guilherme, ready

Comment: @MateusGonçalves, you need to add a `@` before the name

Comment: @thisiskelvin, save and insert are not the same in true code, here is just example

Comment: thanks @AlbertoGuilherme

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran, ready

Comment: @CodeBoyCode , I already include –

Comment: @MateusGonçalves Can you add your routes file.

Comment: okay @thisiskelvin

Comment: @MateusGonçalves - Why do you need to pass to the `CrudController@action` first?

Comment: `StoreFormRequest !== StoreMultipleForm`

Comment: @MateusGonçalves Which one of your routes is using the `UserController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base Http Request class is being injected into your CrudController::action method and the action method is trying to pass that to the UserController::insert method, however, that method requires a StoreFormRequest class, which is a much more specific implementation of the Request class.

This approach won't work because you can't convert a base class instance into a child class instance.

Comment: Because save looks to be a route directed towards the save method instead of being proxied through the action method.

Comment: Ok, I got it. How should I do it in your opinion? I'm new working with laravel.

Comment: I wouldn't try to use inheritance in this manner.  You're assuming all CRUDs will be the same.   You can see here, that's not accurate, because every CRUD may have different inputs, outputs, and requirements.   If you have some logic that needs to be performed on every CRUD, perhaps you could perform that setup in a constructor or use middleware, but I wouldn't try to pass all routes through one controller method.